# How to set default DISPLAY for all SSH sessions?

Tags: ssh

I'm SSH-ing to my PC from my phone, and I have to run `export DISPLAY=:0.0` every time. Is there any way I can set it on my PC so that I don't have to do it on my phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write at the end of your `.bashrc` file:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

You can also have a condition for ssh

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then
    export DISPLAY=:0.0
fi
```

Comment: I pasted your `if..` code in `.bashrc`, didn't work. Directly pasting that line did, though.

Comment: Keep in mind `.bashrc` runs every time you login. If you logout and login it should work, since the environmental variables `SSH_CLIENT` and/or `SSH_CONNECTION` should be set when you enter the machine through the ssh protocol.

Comment: I changed the code for the `if` condition, now it should work with no problems =)